# Unexpected token in JSON when using cURL from php

Tags: php, curl, graphql

Im using Graphql on remote server and php+curl on main server, when im tryin go update or creat new im got an error "Unexpected token ** in JSON at position"

I'm really trying to shielding but is is doesn't help. If im made request from graphql frontend it is works fine.

Fine JSON request:

```
mutation {
  updateMarket(Id: "002384fa-7d45-e911-9c76-00155d056158", Lat: 122, Lng: 1) {
    Id
    Lat
  }
}
```

Php code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '192.168.1.1:4040/graphql');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "mutation {\n  updateMarket(Id: \"002384fa-7d45-e911-9c76-00155d056158\", Lat: 122, Lng: 1) {\n    Id\n    Lat\n  }\n}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Don't create your own json, create an array then use json_encode to make sure it's in a valid format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some times of research Im find a lib "gmostafa/php-graphql-client" (composer require) It is nice instrument for make querys and mutation for Graphql API from php.

Answer (score -1):

It's not correct JSON syntax. What do you want from this "mutation" row?

Comment: Im want to update row whe id=**. When I get a row with "{"query" : "query {  markets { ShopAddress } }"}" is work fine. Thanks!

Comment: As @aynber said - use `json_encode` function for correct JSON format